# Declaring a global property in main file, When used that global property in vue (typescript) template giving syntax error (vscode)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using VueJs with typescript & vite. I have an icons  file contents are following:

```
export const ICONS = {
    CLOCK: 'kbtmbyzy',
    CALENDAR: 'gphxrzct',
}
```

In my main.ts file. I have attached this as a global property, after importing it from the file.

```
app.config.globalProperties.ICONS = ICONS;
```

I have component:

```
<animated-icon :name="ICONS.CLOCK" />
```

[image]

Notice ICONS is highlighted and shows the follow error:

```
Property 'ICONS' does not exist on type '{ $: ComponentInternalInstance; $data: {}; $props: Partial<{}> & Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<{}>> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, never>; ... 10 more ...; $watch(source: string | Function, cb: Function, options?: WatchOptions<...> | undefined): WatchStopHandle; } & ... 4 more ... & Co...'.ts(2339)
```

I am using vue3 composition api. It gives the error when I use composition api with setup in script tag:
`<script setup lang="ts"></script>`
However it doesn't gives the error when used export default:

```
export default {
  setup() {}
}
</script>
```

I want to use first method with setup in the script tag.